# How Add pickup list to DBGrid at run time?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

i have a DBGrid and it is linked to client dataset when i assign a SQLQuery at run time
the DBGrid automatically assigns no of column. What i need is when DBGrid automatically assign columns i need to set one of those columns to assign a picklist.
can anyone help me?
the following procedure calls in the forms on show event. the form contains DataSource, ClientDataSet, SQLViewQuery (TSQLQuery), DatasetProvider and DBGridDetails (TDBGrid).

```
procedure TViewDetailsForm.ViewPendingAndReturnCheques;
var I : Integer;
slPickList:TStringList;
begin
  slPickList := TStringList.Create;
  slPickList.Add('Pending');
  slPickList.Add('Returned');
  slPickList.Add('Passed');

  SQL := 'SELECT a.CHEQUE_NO, a.BANK, a.CHEQUE_DATE, a.AMOUNT,a.STATUS FROM CHEQUES a';

  //refreshisng the DBGrid
  SQLViewQuery.SQL.Clear;
  SQLViewQuery.SQL.Add(SQL);
  ClientDataSet.Active := false;
  ClientDataSet.Active := true;

  DBGridDetails.Columns[0].Width := _Block;
  DBGridDetails.Columns[1].Width := _Block;
  DBGridDetails.Columns[2].Width := _Block;
  DBGridDetails.Columns[3].Width := _Block;
  DBGridDetails.Columns[4].Width := _Block;


  for I := 0 to DBGridDetails.Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if DBGridDetails.Columns[I].FieldName = 'STATUS' then
    begin
       DBGridDetails.Columns[i].ButtonStyle := cbsAuto;
       DBGridDetails.Columns[I].PickList := slPickList;
    end;
  end;

  Show;

end;
```

Comment: Have you seen [`this tutorial`](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa101403a.htm) ?

Comment: "but not works" is not helpful. If you've tried something, [edit] your question to include what you've tried, and explain how it doesn't work. You also need to define "picklist". Is it a list of hard-coded values ("Choice A, Choice B, Choice C"), or is it a list of values from another table?

Comment: i added my code _Block = 70 (Const)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample app I just created in Delphi 2007 that demonstrates how to accomplish this. Here's all I did to set it up:

1. Click File->New-VCL Forms Application from the IDE's main menu.
2. Drop a *TClientDataSet*, a *TDataSource*, and a *TDBGrid* on the form.
3. Click on the form, and then use the Object Inspector to create a new *OnCreate* event handler. Add the following code:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   var
     SL: TStringList;
   begin
     with ClientDataSet1 do
     begin
       FieldDefs.Clear;
       FieldDefs.Add('OrderNo', ftInteger);
       FieldDefs.Add('Status', ftString, 10);
       CreateDataSet;
     end;
     ClientDataSet1.Active := True;

     // Connect a datasource to the CDS
     DataSource1.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

     // Connect the grid to that datasource to create the columns.
     DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;

     // Create the picklist for the second column (Status)
     SL := TStringList.Create;
     try
       SL.Add('Pending');
       SL.Add('Returned');
       SL.Add('Passed');
       DBGrid1.Columns[1].ButtonStyle := cbsAuto;
       DBGrid1.Columns[1].PickList := SL;
     finally
       SL.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```
4. Run the application, click in the `Status` column in the grid, and you'll see the three choices added to the `PickList` above.

[image: Image of DBGrid with PickList displayed]

Comment: is there any way to set the picklist after activating the clientdataset ?

Comment: I just did that, in the code above. (It has `ClientDataSet1.Active := True;` before the picklist is added.) ???

Comment: you defined the columns first isn't ? in my case columns are created according to no of resulting columns by the query.

Comment: There are no columns in my grid at design time, and there are none in the ClientDataSet. It works exactly the same way as yours does; the columns are created based on the new columns I've added in code, which is *exactly* like creating them based on assigning a query.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign values to the dbgrid column picklist during the run time.

Below is the code:
procedure Tfrm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  slPickList:TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
    slPickList := TStringList.Create;
    slPickList.Add('Pending');
    slPickList.Add('Returned');
    slPickList.Add('Passed');
    for I := 0 to 2 do
    begin
       dbgViewAxiomClaims.Columns[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8zL5.png).PickList.add(slPickList[i]);//assigning
  end;
  end;

Below is the result:

[image]

Comment: I gave this exact answer 15 months before you posted this one.